# make a dimensional array from object

Tags: javascript

I get this data from the backend

```
let procedure_word_count = [{"slug":"new","name":"New","count":1},{"slug":"no-need","name":"No Need","count":2},{"slug":"why","name":"Why","count":2}]
```

My goal is to create a dimensional array that extracts the name and count from the "procedure_word_count"

```
let newArray = "[['New', 1], ['No Need', 2], ['Why', 2]]"
```

Comment: Why is `newArray` a string?

Comment: `"procedure_word_count" = [...]` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can always **map** it and create an array from the object:

```js
let example = [
  {"slug":"new","name":"New","count":1},
  {"slug":"no-need","name":"No Need","count":2},
  {"slug":"why","name":"Why","count":2}
];

let result = example.map((item) => [item.name, item.count]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you retrieve from the server can be iterated over using the [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

`.map()` iterates over each element and builds an array.. The function returns whatever you want - in this case the `name` and `count` properties.

```js
const input = [{"slug":"new","name":"New","count":1},{"slug":"no-need","name":"No Need","count":2},{"slug":"why","name":"Why","count":2}];

const output = input.map(o=>[o.name,o.count]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element so it's a classic for this one. for each iteration the function will return an array containing the selected keys values.

```js
const arr = [{"slug":"new","name":"New","count":1},{"slug":"no-need","name":"No Need","count":2},{"slug":"why","name":"Why","count":2}];

const res = arr.map(x => [x.name, x.count]);
console.log(res);
```